# How do I get my text array fill up from an local file.?

Tags: split

Using P5js, I'm trying to get text elements from a local text file into an array.
pets.txt contains cat dog on new lines.

Hopefully this code explains the problem. Thanks for looking!

```
var pets;
var petArray = [];

function preload() {
.
.
.

    pets = loadStrings("pets.txt");
    petArray = pets.splitText(',');
}


function draw() {
.
.
.
       fill(0);
       textSize(20);
       text(pets,60,height-10);      //prints...    cat,dog
       text("X" + petArray[1],160,height-10); //prints...   Xundefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems 'pets' is already an array - so didn't need
petArray = pets.splitText(',');

I don't know why the above doesn't work but I've sorted my problem of getting a text file into an array.